# Load a module to run before dom ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I can't figure out how to load the `jQuery`, `jQueryValidate` and `jQueryValidateUnobtrusive` using `require.js` with custom validation rules in such a way that the module runs before the dom ready. The custom rules are written as modules (e.g. `someCustomValidator.js`). The way `jQueryValidateUnobtrusive` works is that the `someCustomValidator` should be run after `jQuery`, `jQueryValidate` and `jQueryValidateUnobtrusive` have been loaded but before `$.ready` is fired. First condition is easy, the module `someCustomValidator` depends on `jQuery`, `jQueryValidate` and `jQueryValidateUnobtrusive`. It is the second part that I am stuck at. The `app.js` is loaded just before the closing body tag and so in most of the cases by the time the `someCustomValidator` are loaded and run, the `domReady` has already fired. How do I setup the dependencies to satisfy the requirement of `someCustomValidator should be run after jQuery, jQueryValidate and jQueryValidateUnobtrusive have been loaded but before $.ready is fired`. I thought about using [holdReady](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/) but I am not sure when to call it and in what module.

The actual definitions `validatorSetup.js` and `someCustomValidator.js` are not very important but I am including the basic setup below for completeness.

HTML

```
...
...
<script src="SomePath/RequireJS/require.js"></script>
<script>
require(["app"]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
require([
        "jquery",
        "someCustomValidator",
        "anotherCustomValidator"
], function ($,
            someCustomValidator,
            anotherCustomValidator) {

    // Validators should be configured before dom ready.
    someCustomValidator.init();
    anotherCustomValidator.init();

    $(function () {
        // Stuff that should run after dom ready
        someModule1.init();
        someModule2.init();
    });
});
```

validatorSetup.js

```
define("validatorSetup", ["jquery", "jquery-validate", "jquery-validate-unobtrusive"], (function ($) {
    var validatorSetup = {
        init: function() {
            this.setDefaults();
        },

        setDefaults:function() {
            this.setIgnore();
        },

        setIgnore: function() {
            $.validator.setDefaults({
                ignore: ":hidden, .ignore"
            });
        }
    };

    return validatorSetup;
}));
```

someCustomValidator.js

```
define("someCustomValidator", ["validatorSetup", "jquery", "jquery-validate", "jquery-validate-unobtrusive"], (function (validatorSetup, $) {
    var someCustomValidator = {
        init: function () {
            validatorSetup.setIgnore();

            this.setUpValidationRule();
        },

        setUpValidationRule: function () {
            $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
                "somerule",
                ["someprop", "rule", "ruleparam"],
                function (options) {
                    options.rules["somerule"] = options.params;
                    options.messages["propertydependencyrule"] = options.message;
                }
            );

            $.validator.addMethod(
                "somerule",
                function (value, element, params) {
                    var rule = params.rule;
                    var ruleParams = params.ruleparam;

                    //Some logic

                    return $.validator.methods[rule].call(this, value, element, ruleParams);
                },
                ""
            );
        }
    };

    return someCustomValidator;
}));
```

Comment: A problem is that `require()` is asynchronous and does not block so the page may finish loading before `require()` is done.  `<script>` tags present in the page are blocking so if you could use that instead to load the things you need loaded first, those would get loaded before the DOM was ready.

Comment: Yes I understand. I have made sure that there are no script that isn't loaded via require. Even if I am willing to make exception for these three scripts it would present challenge as every custom validator module would have to be loaded that way. jQuery would have to be loaded as module also because there are other modules that depend on it. Is it possible to load a script both via a script tag and as a module?

Comment: Well your title asks how to get a script to be loaded before the DOM is ready.  If you're dynamically loading the script with `require()`, you can't guarantee it will be loaded before the DOM.  You just can't.  But, I suspect that isn't really the ACTUAL problem you're trying to solve.  Probably you want to make sure some other piece of code runs after the scripts are loaded and before something else runs.  If you can express that actual problem in a clearer way, we can probably help you with the actual problem.  I know you're trying to explain that, but I don't follow.  Please clarify.

Comment: The library jQueryValidateUnobtrusive adapts the server side validation logic to jQueryValidate lib. It uses dom ready internally to do that. If we want to use custom validation logic that has to be done before the dom ready. This all works fine if each of those scripts are in the page using script tag but doesn't work because of async loading of requirejs. I do have a work around but it isn't efficient and so I am trying to see if there is a better way.

Comment: Why not add a small module that loads after jQuery and wrangle the ready function. Something like `$.readyNow = $ready; $.ready = function(stuff){ //do your stuff; $.readyNow(stuff); // your done so let jquery do its thing` No reason you can not replace jquery functions with your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reorganized the dependencies in this way and the dom ready is head until it is released later after the `someCustomValidator.js` has been loaded.

app.js

```
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    // Hold the domready
    $.holdReady(true);

    require([
            "jquery",
            "someCustomValidator",
            "anotherCustomValidator"
    ], function ($,
                someCustomValidator,
                anotherCustomValidator) {

        // Validators should be configured before dom ready.
        someCustomValidator.init();
        anotherCustomValidator.init();

        // The custom validations have been attached.
        // Now it is ok to let the dom ready to fire
        $.holdReady(false);

        $(function () {
            // Stuff that should run after dom ready
            someModule1.init();
            someModule2.init();
        });
    });
});
```